# How to re-render a MaterialTable after updating a specific row in the DB using Redux (Action + Reducer)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-table

Suppose we have the following code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getLeadsNotValid,
  updateSpecificNotValidLead
} from "../../actions/leads";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";

const MisleadLeadsTable = ({
  getLeadsNotValid,
  loadingData,
  leadsNotValid,
  updateSpecificNotValidLead
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // goes to the action and gets the leads from the DB
    getLeadsNotValid();   
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [getLeadsNotValid]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loadingData ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <MaterialTable
          title="Problematic Leads"
          columns={[
            { title: "BusinessName", field: "BusinessName" },
            { title: "City", field: "City" },
            { title: "Rooms", field: "Rooms", type: "numeric" },
            {
              title: "Phone Number",
              field: "PhoneNumberMasque"
            },
            {
              title: "Supplier",
              field: "supplier.name"
            }
          ]}
          data={leadsNotValid}
          editable={{
            onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => {
              new Promise(resolve => {
                // Goes to the DB and updates the new data
                updateSpecificNotValidLead(newData);

                // TODO : Needs to re-render the table
              });
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loadingData: state.leadReducer.loadingData,
  leadsNotValid: state.leadReducer.leadsNotValid
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getLeadsNotValid, updateSpecificNotValidLead };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MisleadLeadsTable);
```

After a specific row has been updated (updates successfully , checked and verified) I want to re-render the table.

I'm using Redux the fetch the data from the Backend (Mongo DB) however after I'm sending 
the row to the server I get :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

How can I re render the component with the new data using Redux ?

**EDIT :**

Action :

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID,
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS,
  UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID,
  UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD
} from "./types";

export const updateSpecificNotValidLead = updatedLead => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD
  });

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify({ updatedLead });

  const res = await axios.post(
    ".......API/Something1/....",
    body,
    config
  );

  if (res !== null && res.data !== null) {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID
    });
  }
};


export const getLeadsNotValid = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID
  });

  const res = await axios.get(".......API/Something2/....");
  if (res !== null && res.data !== null) {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  }
};
```

**Reducer :**

```
import {
  GET_MAIN_LEADS_SUCCESS,
  REQUEST_MAIN_LEADS,
  RELOAD_DATA_MAIN_LEADS_TABLE,
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID,
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS,
  UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD,
  UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  mainLeadsClients: [],
  loadingData: null, // general loader
  reloadMainLeadTable: 0,
  reloadMisleadTable: 0,
  leadsNotValid: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingData: true
      };

    case REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingData: false,
        leadsNotValid: payload
      };
    case UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingData: true
      };
    case UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID:
      return {
        ...state,
        reloadMisleadTable: state.reloadMisleadTable + 1,
        loadingData: false
      };


    // ... more 

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you both import  getLeadsNotValid and updateSpecificNotValidLead from your action, and also reading them from props? It seems to me they must not be read from props here `const MisleadLeadsTable = ({getLeadsNotValid, loadingData,leadsNotValid, updateSpecificNotValidLead})`

Comment: @SuleymanSah: For Redux (and that's not the problem).

Comment: Hmmm, I have never seen such usage. Where did you find that usage? It seems suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

You do not return the promise in your editable prop.
 That's why then is undefined because no promise is returned. Change it to:

```
  editable={{
          onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => new Promise(resolve => {
            // Goes to the DB and updates the new data
            updateSpecificNotValidLead(newData);

            // TODO : Needs to re-render the table
          });
      }}
```

That should fix it.